# Are static locals of function template specializations with T=<unnamed namespaced class> required to be unique?

Tags: c++, templates, static, undefined-behavior, icc

We use the Intel C++ compiler and detected that it miscompiles (?) the following, reduced from a use of `boost::function<Ponies()> f(unnamedNamespacedFunctor)`.

a1.cc:

```
template<typename T>
int f(T) { static int x = T::x; return x; }


namespace { struct A { static const int x = 1; }; }

int f1() {
   return f(A());
}
```

a2.cc:

```
template<typename T>
int f(T) { static int x = T::x; return x; }


namespace { struct A { static const int x = 0; }; }

int f2() {
   return f(A());
}
```

main.cc:

```
#include <cstdio>

int f1();
int f2();

int main() {
   std::printf("%d != %d\n", f1(), f2());
}
```

Command line:

```
# icpc a1.cc a2.cc main.cc -o main
# ./main
0 != 0
```

My question is: Is this compliant? Does using static locals in such instantiations produce undefined behavior? When inspecting the produced symbols, I noted that while `f` is has local linkage, as I suspected, the `x` static variable receives weak linkage and therefore the two `x`'es are merged and it becomes lottery which is chosen

```
# icpc a2.cc a1.cc main.cc -o main
# ./main
1 != 1
```

I would be grateful for help. Perhaps this is actually a compiler-bug after all and it has already been reported?

Comment: does this also occur if you rename one of the `struct A` to e.g. `struct B`?

Comment: Isn't the definition of `f` in violation of the ODR? What happens if you put the two defintions of `f` in their respective local namespaces to fix the ODR-violation?

Comment: @MSalters the same happens with boost::function, which I cannot change so easily :) If it is an ODR violation, I guess it's against existing practice. I haven't found a rule that forbids this. The linkage of the function template instantiation is external, but the argument type has internal linkage (and hence is a different type in different TUs!). I can't find a paragraph that forbids it, and I'm not sure there is a reason to forbid it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: How do you end up with two definitions of Boost.function? Macro? The ODR mainly says that the token sequences have to be identical, but of course the token meaning may differ after instantiation. That's the whole point of templates after all.

Comment: @MSalters I simply create a `boost::function<int()>  f(MyTuLocalFunctor());` and it randomly substitutes the behavior of one's .cc functor into the behavior of the other .cc's functor. And it turned out the reason is that it merges the static locals, which boost::function uses to implement its type erasure internally.

Comment: If you ensure that the instantiations of `f<T>` don't get inlined into `f1` and `f2` (perhaps with `__attribute__((noinline))`), you should be able to see if those instantiations have the same name mangling or not. According to the Itanium C++ ABI, name mangling of a function-scope name includes the name mangling of the function, and I would definitely expect the two instantiations to have different name mangling. I suspect icpc has a bug in the presence of inlining.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: static locals within a function (template), outside any anonymous namespace? I can imagine that name mangling then fails to produce distinct names.

Comment: @865719 I think that my case is not the same because while the template is the same, two different functions are instantiated because according to 14.4p1 "Type equivalence", "Two template-ids refer to the same class or function if ... their corresponding type template-arguments are the same type". In my case, the two types are different (because they have internal linkage and they are defined in two TUs. Therefore, by 14.8p2 "Each function template specialization instantiated from a template has its own copy of any static variable."

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek: It appears that the compiler (quite reasonably) deduces that such name mangling is not necessary because it takes an ODR-violation to detect it.

Comment: @MSalters Name mangling happens inside a single translation unit, and `f<A#1>` and `f<A#2>` would need different mangling even if they were instantiated from exactly the same template. Even if there is an ODR violation in this example (which there probably is), I would expect the name mangling of the two statics to be different.

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek it seems to me that the mangling of an entity inside of a unnamed namespace is always the same (not really surprising, because otherwise the compiler would need to come up with uniqe names each time it compiles a TU that contains such entities). That wouldn't be itself a problem if the generated function and instantiations that depend on it would not show up in the exported symbols list (and the functions that ICC emits actually have local linkage.. just not that static data member..).

Comment: I think you can avoid ODR violation and still produce a failure case, which means there is probably a bug. Just make the initializer of your static `x` use a constant or enum defined differently in each version of `A`. Weak linkage of the static makes sense because it has to be merged with other copies of the same instantiation, but that is incompatible with a name that is not mangled to contain the "identity" of the unnamed namespace.

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek ah I see what the error is, now. OK, this is obvious. I'll change it and try again

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Because you have two definitions of `f` in the global namespace with a different sequence of tokens in their definitions? I don't think the letter of the ODR law cares about linkage in this case.

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek fixed and indeed it still fails :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me. Letting `A1` be one of the instantiations of `A` and `A2` be the other:

I presume that the static `x` has weak linkage so that the linker can merge copies of the static between multiple copies of the *same* instantiation. (If you managed to instantiate `f<A1>` in two different translation units, for example.)

Either `f<A1>` and `f<A2>` should have different name mangling, which would cause the two versions of `x` to have different name mangling (I think some compilers actually generate a random value to make names inside anonymous namespaces unique), or else `x` should not have internal linkage (because a local type was used to instantiate `f`, which should make it impossible to replicate in another translation unit).